# Setup Unity Smart Merge

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to setup UnityYAMLMerge as merge tool with Unity 5.3.1 and Git in Windows 10.

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to make it work. Here's what I've done based on what I've read on these links:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html
https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/39bdq5/how_to_solve_scene_conflicts_with_unitys_smart/

1) Set up both .gitconfig (global) and .git/config (local project) by adding this:

[merge]
tool = unityyamlmerge

[mergetool "unityyamlmerge"]
trustExitCode = false
cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\UnityYAMLMerge.exe merge' -p "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"

2) Installed Perforce P4V and added merge apps

3) Set up mergespecfile.txt modifying the uncommented lines so they look like this:
unity use "C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe" "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
prefab use "C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4merge.exe" "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"

Me and my teammate have edited a scene, and when I pull the changes (git bash) it just shows me the typical error message:
warning: Cannot merge binary files: Assets/Scenes/GameScene.unity (HEAD vs. 81d75fc59feed35563a24b8dd609fa29deb5ec46)
Auto-merging Assets/Scenes/GameScene.unity
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in Assets/Scenes/GameScene.unity
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something. I hope someone can help us.

Thanks.

Comment: the files are considered binary. you need to override their type in [.gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). you also may wish to configure diff/merge tool on the file type basis here.

Comment: this has no connection at all to StackOverflow.  Perhaps try one of the sys admin site?  Note that (i) you can't "merge" binaries (video, music, images), you can only "merge" computer code. (ii) git is poorly suited for Unity3d,  subversion is very popular for the game business

Comment: there're so many git-git related questions at SO, and this one doesn't seem a complete offtopic. One can merge any type of files including binary ones, if it's possible to define a reasonable semi-automated procedure of deriving a resulting file from the three predecessors: a base, a variant A, a variant B. Certainly one need special, dedicated for  a particular file-type diff-ing and merging tools for all the cases beyond ordinary text files. That's the reason why @OscarB92 tries to configure that `UnityYamlMerge` tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled "Force Text" serilization mode in Unity, you need "unity" and "prefab" files do not been merged automatically by git.
So you need add following content to `.gitattributes`:

`*.unity binary
*.prefab binary`

When you merged a branch in git, git won't merge unity and prefab file, just left conflicted files.
Then you need run `git mergetool` manually to trigger `UnityYAMLMerge`. It's a very important step!

By the way, you don't need to run anything in mercurial, just merge a branch would trigger `UnityYAMLMerge`.